# Batch rename folders that contain specific criteria

Tags: batch-file

I am looking rename folders that have specific criteria with a batch file.

Rename folders that have the months (January, February, March) with the numeric values (01, 02, 03)

John Smith June 2016 would be John Smith 06-2016
Jane Smith October 2015 would be Jane Smith 10-2015

Comment: Batchfile programming is perfectly OK here on SuperUser, but we are indeed not a "please write me a script" service. Share your research and we'll help you point out where things aren't working.

Comment: I don't know the best way to approach it as I am not familiar with batch files. Not looking for it to get written, just need an idea of a place to start.

Comment: @ejbytes Please don't add such comments. **Batch file questions are on topic** but user are expected to make an effort first.

Comment: "I am not familiar with batch files" there are plenty of tutorials. Note: Asking for us to recommend tutorial is off-topic. If you don't want to learn then you should pay someone to to the work instead of expecting volunteers to do the work for you.

Comment: It's very difficult to tell you where to start since it's impossible to know what your skills are; specifically what programming skills you have, if any.  I suggest you take a look at [Code Academy](https://www.codecademy.com/) for an intro to scripting and then continue from there.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a batch style solution, but it can be useful.
There is a software where you can specify certain criteria to rename lots of files.
This software is free for home use, is called

[Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Download.php)